# how to sort element based on a date with javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting

I am using Filterizr as a template to show our publications.
I have inserted publication year and authors.
When trying to sort basing on year of publication or on authors (alphabetically), i see the images mooving but then i don't get the right order.
Can any one of you help me fix this sorting problem ?

```
https://jsfiddle.net/gdhia/yLdtmeqL/
```

In their page they say things i don't understand:

> .filterizr('sort' [,attr] [,sortOrder])
>
> Sort your elements based on the a certain attribute attribute in ascending or descending order and rearrange them on screen.
>
> ```
> attr (typeof: String / Default: 'domIndex')
>
> The attribute based on which the elements are sorted. If not provided it defaults to value 'domIndex' and the elements are sorted based on their initial position in the DOM. If its value is set to 'sortData', the elements are sorted based on the value of the user-defined data-sort attribute. Other possible values includes 'w' or 'h' if you wish to sort your elements by width or height (used for layouts of items of different size).
> ```

Comment: The code for your question goes **in** your question, not just linked -- which is why SO wouldn't let you post that fiddle link without marking it up inappropriately as code.

Comment: you're probably comparing the dates as string, which means `Feb 1/2016` will sort as **OLDER** than `Apr 1/2016` - string comparison rules don't work with dates.

Comment: @Marc, lexicographical comparison works just fine with ISO 8601 dates, just not with aberrations like `MMM d/yyyy`.

Comment: then almost certainly OP's dates aren't in a most-significant-first ordering, otherwise a convention sorting would "just work".

Comment: In fact, I'm using just dates: 2010, 2011, ... for the "item-position" and words like "WWF" in "item-desc" (item description"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am Filterizr's author,
are you using the preset Filterizr controls?

If you would like to sort your items by author name, then you need to include that author name on every item in the data-sort attribute of every element.
e.g.

```
<div class="filtr-item" data-sort="Author name"></div>
```

Then your sort controls will do the rest of your work for you.

If you want to call the public method, then you simply do

```
//to instantiate your filterizr
var fltr = $('.filtr-container').filterizr(); 
//then to sort, since sortData will be now referring to authors' names
fltr.filterizr('sort', 'sortData', 'asc');
```

---

**Update**: Since apparently you want to sort by multiple criteria, I added the ability to Filterizr to sort by custom, user-defined data-attributes.
Make sure to grab the latest Filterizr version from the GitHub repo and try this:

```
<div class="filtr-item" data-author="Author Name" data-publishyear="1990"></div>
```

Then call:

```
fltr.filterizr('sort', 'author', 'asc') //to sort by author name
fltr.filterizr('sort', 'publishyear', 'asc') //to sort by publish year
```

To add controls for your custom data attribute just add to your select input:

```
<option value="author">Author Name</option>
<option value="publishyear">Publish Year</option>
```

You can add as many data-attributes for sorting as you want, just remember to not include the "data-" part when passing their names as arguments. I have also added an in-depth sorting tutorial on the Filterizr website. Enjoy!